# Background opacity working in ie7 and ie9, but not ie8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

My main css file has:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 760px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
    background: #ffffff;
    /* RGBa with 0.8 opacity */
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

Using conditional comments in the head, my ie.css file has:

```
#wrapper {
    background: transparent;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CCFFFFFF,endColorstr=#CCFFFFFF)";
    /* IE8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CCFFFFFF,endColorstr=#CCFFFFFF);
    /* IE6 & 7 */
    zoom: 1;
}
```

This works fine in ie7 and ie9, but the background is appearing transparent in ie8.

Comment: If you switch the order of the **filter** and **-ms-filter** attributes, does it work then?

Comment: I had high hopes for that suggestion as it makes sense, but unfortunately not.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue. It seems to work fine in IE 8. Can you reproduce it with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: It seems to work on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QZswz/1/embedded/result/

Comment: I've temporarily enabled the site where it happens: http://www.champagnesparklingwwc.co.uk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked on a colleague's laptop in IE 8 and it's working fine. Seems the problem is with ietester.